# For loop doesn't add values to a points collection

Tags: c#, for-loop, arcgis

The for loop doesn't add any value to my points collection:

```
Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.PointCollection VMM40Points = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.PointCollection(Spatialreference);
            for (int i = 1; i == xyz.Count/3; i += 3)
            {
                VMM40Points.Add(xyz[i - 1], xyz[i], xyz[i + 1]);
            }
```

this is the debugger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZXwA.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "while" portion of the for loop was incorrect: it runs *while* the condition is true, not *until*.

I'm not sure why you have `[i -1]`. Is there a special reason? If not, you are making the loop conditions much more complicated than necessary.

```
var VMM40Points = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.PointCollection(Spatialreference); 
for (int i = 0; i < xyz.Count; i+=3)
{
    VMM40Points.Add(xyz[i], xyz[i + 1], xyz[i + 2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to `i < xyz.Count/3`.

Comment: that's only one problem. no effort -1

Comment: @ShaiCohen what is the other problem?